# Celery scheduled task executing immediately instead of delaying

Tags: django, redis, celery, django-celery, celery-task

I am trying to schedule a Celery task for execution using : `mytask.apply_async(countdown=120)`(`mytask` is a simple python method with `@task` decorator). However when I call that, the task is executed immediately instead of executing it after 2 minutes and returns result like `<EagerResult: 2b41cba1-81ff-489c-81bb-f1ad994d4441>`. Any idea what I am missing here? I have also tried to do this using `eta` instead of `countdown`. My celery configuration is given below:

`-- v3.0.12 (Chiastic Slide)

[Configuration]

-- broker:      redis://localhost:6379/0

-- app:         default:0x106090f50 (djcelery.loaders.DjangoLoader)

-- concurrency: 4 (processes)

-- events:      OFF (enable -E to monitor this worker)

[Queues]

-- celery:      exchange:celery(direct) binding:celery`

If it helps, I am starting my celery this way:  `python manage.py celeryd -l DEBUG -B` and have got periodic crontasks to work properly.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you don't have settings.CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER set to true?

Comment: Thanks @PopcornArsonist . That was indeed the problem. You might want to add it as an answer :)